# Rails - how to avoid validation errors in creating a record in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am working on Facebook authentication for Devise and I stumbled upon one problem - when will try to sign up someone with Facebook email that is already in the system, I get an error (which is partially correct).

I would need to redirect this user back to the homepage and there to print out this issue, but at the moment I am having this message printed as an error (on localhost).

Here's how I am doing that (**user** model):

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info

    if user = User.where(:provider => 'facebook', :uid => data.id).first
      user
    else # Create a user with a stub password. 
      user = User.create!(:first_name => data.first_name,
                          :last_name => data.last_name,
                          :email => data.email, 
                          :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                          :provider => 'facebook',
                          :uid => data.id,
                          :terms_of_use => true) 
    end
    return user if user
  end
```

How to redirect the user on a page where would be printed out the validation messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have something like this in your model and controller

**`Return just the user object from the method`**

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info
    #Look for the first user with provider: :facebook & uid: data.id,
    #If now user is there go ahead and create one with first_or_create.
    user = User.where(:provider => 'facebook', :uid => data.id).first_or_create do |user|
           user.first_name = data.first_name,
           user.last_name = data.last_name,
           user.email = data.email,
           user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
           user.provider = 'facebook',
           user.uid = data.id,
           user.terms_od_use = true
          end
  end
```

**`Controller`**

```
def sign_in_method #dummy method
  user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  if user.valid?
    redirect success_url #any url where u want to redirect on success 
  else user.errors
     redirect root_url, error: user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of first_or_create? This piece of code is awful.

Comment: i know it's super bad.  I wanted to give him a idea of how to take errors and redirect, rather refactor.  Because that's what he asked.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, added `first_or_create` ;)